# Finding Edges of a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to find the weight of the edges of a graph by using the output of the Prim's algorithm.

**Note: In a graph has n edges, each edge is different and between 1-n.**

For example:

```
Vertices = {A, B, C, D, E}
Edges = {B-D, D-E, E-A, C-B, A-D, D-C, A-C}
Extract_Min() Order = B D C A E
```

By using the information above, I want to find the weight of each edge. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The solution does not have to be unique.

Comment: There is no unique solution.

Comment: I just want a solution, It does not have to be unique.

Comment: @G.Bach I overread that:D

Comment: Yep, I guess that is a good way to exploit missing restrictions in the problem statement

Comment: This can't be solved if all weights are different and there are fewer weights than edges, so I guess you forgot to mention something.

Comment: In the example, there are 5 vertices so the weight of each edge must be between 1 and 5. And there will be no duplicate. `Weights = {1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: @g3d But there are 7 edges. That's just not possible

Comment: @g3d But there are 7 edges in the example, so there *must* be either duplicates, or weights outside the range, one or the other. Basic pigeonhole argument... Unless the weights really belong to the nodes, but then the concept of the weight of an edge needs to be defined.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I changed it.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Seems like you just want us to solve your homework, rather than asking a specific question

Comment: Try greedy, no reason that shouldn't work here.

Comment: Agreed with @G.Bach, greedily assigning increasing edge weights will work (I thought they'd need to be exponentially increasing before, but that's not true for MST)

Answer (score 1):

By your example:

```
Vertices = {A, B, C, D, E}
Edges = {B-D, D-E, E-A, C-B, A-D, D-C, A-C}
Extract_Min() Order = B D C A E
```

Look at the order given by `Extract_Min()`.
The edge with weight 1 is surely `B-D`.
Assign weight 2 to some single edge from the set `{B,D}` to `C`.
Assign weight 3 to some single edge from the set `{B,D,C}` to `A`.
Assign weight 4 to some single edge from the set `{B,D,C,A}` to `E`.
Assign the remaining weights to the remaining edges in any order.